# jQuery selector to select first element of each letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I have a quick question about jQuery selector.
I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li class="ln-a"></li>
    <li class="ln-b"></li>
    <li class="ln-b"></li>
    <li class="ln-b"></li>
    <li class="ln-c"></li>
    <li class="ln-f"></li>
    <li class="ln-f"></li>
    <li class="ln-f"></li>
</ul>
```

My question is: How can I select only the first li from each letter? Is it possible to have just CSS selector?

I've tried: `jQuery('li:regexp(class, ln-.*):first').addClass('separator');` but this does not work as expected.

Comment: Do you mean first letter in each `<li>`

Comment: I don't think this will be possible with a single selector - although I'm happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: I agree with Rory, I think this will require iterating over the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see how to do it with a single selector. Here's a method to do it by iterating the elements. I'm sure there are other ways to do this...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[class^="ln-"]').each(function(ind, ele) {
    var cls = $(ele).attr('class');
    $('.' + cls).first().addClass('seperator');
  });
});
```

```css
.seperator {
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="ln-a">a</li>
  <li class="ln-b">b</li>
  <li class="ln-b">b</li>
  <li class="ln-b">b</li>
  <li class="ln-c">c</li>
  <li class="ln-f">f</li>
  <li class="ln-f">f</li>
  <li class="ln-f">f</li>
</ul>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like someone actually read the question.  Well done.   That said, this solution seems to be doing the `addClass` on every loop...can be optimized a little more I'm sure; but definitely solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @technophobia Yeah, first I pushed unique classes into an array, and then iterated that to add the `separator` class, but then decided to reduce the code to the bare minimum for this example.

Comment: Alternatively, a `tempCls` can be used to hold the previous value - then it can be compared with the current `cls` before applying the `separator` class.  But, like you said, legibility trumps complexity when explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an 'nth-of-class' implementation in jQuery. I don't think you can do this without iterating like Ted's good and flexible answer.

However as you asked for a CSS solution as well then below is a terrible way to solve your problem with just CSS. I wouldn't do this as it depends on your css classes being rigid and predictable but if you know your `li`'s will always be this way it would do the trick.

```
.ln-a:first-child,
.ln-a + .ln-b,
.ln-b + .ln-c {
    background: red;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cs1fp3tt/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to resolve your question:

1. Select all `li` elements that class has `li-` prefix

   That task could be done with jQuery **[prefix](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)** selection: **[name|=”value”]**

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-).

2. Filter any but the first occurrence of the element with a given class
   This could be done using jQuery **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method, which checks if given node is the same as first node.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

Below code has it both implemented:

```js
$("li[class|=ln]")
  .filter(function() {
    var klass = $(this).attr('class');
    var $firstNode = $(this).parent().find('.' + klass + ':first');
    return $(this)[0] === $firstNode[0];
  })
  .addClass('seperator')
```

```css
.seperator {
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ln-a"></li>
  <li class="ln-b"></li>
  <li class="ln-b"></li>
  <li class="ln-b"></li>
  <li class="ln-c"></li>
  <li class="ln-f"></li>
  <li class="ln-f"></li>
  <li class="ln-f"></li>
</ul>
```